# python - Get an inverted float matrix with sympy and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy

I'm trying to implement some algorithm on python. For the sake of documentation and clear understanding of the flow details I use sympy. As it turned out it fails on computation of an inverted float matrix.

So I'm getting

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-c2193b2ae217> in <module>()
     10 np.linalg.inv(xx)
     11 symInv = lambdify(X0,X0Inv)
---> 12 symInv(xx)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <lambda>(X0)

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

If the matrix is integer it works fine:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
init_printing()


X0 = MatrixSymbol('X0',2,2)
xx = np.random.rand(4,4) 
#xx = np.random.randint(10,size=(4,4)) # this line makes it workable
X0Inv = X0**-1
np.linalg.inv(xx)
symInv = lambdify(X0,X0Inv)
symInv(xx)
```

[Link to a live version of the code](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/5d120532-1198-40a1-9fdc-4eb988bce2f7/?i=true)

If anybody knows any workaround it would be great if you could share. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**. As it is pointed out by @hpaulj and @tel the issue is how `lambdify` translates `**` to numpy code for matrix symbols: by some reason it tries to XOR elements. I will try to find an easy way to alter this behavior. Any help/hints are appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: So the problem is in the `symInv(xx)` line.  Do you have any evidence (from docs) that this symbol function is supposed to work with a numpy array?

Comment: Your `symInv` doesn't make sense; try `symInv(10)`, why does it produce `-11`?  It also raises an error with`symInv(10.0)`.  In numpy terms it is `np.bitwise_xor(xx, -1)`.

Comment: Evidently `sympy` is converting the `**` operator to `^`, but in numpy that's the logical `xor`, not power.  Also this is an elementwise operation, where as you want a matrix inversion.  In numpy `1/xx` is not the matrix inverse.

Comment: @hpaulj, Right and I wonder if there is a way to affect that conversion somehow..

Comment: Do you want elementwise or matrix inverse?  As you can see in numpy matrix inversion is a special function, not an operator.  In fact it probably is a linaralg solve, I/M.

Comment: `np.matrix` has mapped `**` on to `np.linalg.matrix_power`.  So `np.matrix(x)**-1` produces the matrix inverse.  But I don't see that helping with this sympy iterface.  This class also has a `getI` method and `I` property.

Comment: `print(f.__doc__)` provides useful information on the lambdified function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hpaulj points out, the error seems to stem from a conversion of `**` to `^` that happens in `lambdify`, for some reason.

You can fix the error that you're getting by using `np.power` instead of `**`:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, lambdify

X0 = MatrixSymbol('X0',2,2)
xx = np.random.rand(4,4)
X0Inv = np.power(X0, -1)
symInv = lambdify(X0,X0Inv)

print('matrix xx')
print(xx, end='\n\n')
print('result of symInv(xx)')
print(symInv(xx), end='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
matrix xx
[[0.4514882  0.84588859 0.02431252 0.25468078]
 [0.46767727 0.85748153 0.51207567 0.59636962]
 [0.84557537 0.38459205 0.76814414 0.96624407]
 [0.0933803  0.43467119 0.77823338 0.58770188]]

result of symInv(xx)
[[2.214897321138516, 1.1821887747951494], [2.1382266426713077, 1.1662058776397513]]
```

However, as you have it set up `symInv` doesn't produce the matrix inverse, but instead only does the element-wise exponentiation of each value in `xx`. In other words, `symInv(xx)[i,j] == xx[i,j]**-1`. This code shows the difference between element-wise exponentiation and the true inverse.

```
print('result of xx**-1')
print(xx**-1, end='\n\n')
print('result of np.linalg.inv(xx)')
print(np.linalg.inv(xx))
```

Output:

```
result of xx**-1
[[ 2.21489732  1.18218877 41.13107402  3.92648394]
 [ 2.13822664  1.16620588  1.95283638  1.67681243]
 [ 1.18262669  2.60015778  1.301839    1.0349352 ]
 [10.7088969   2.30058954  1.28496159  1.70154295]]

result of np.linalg.inv(xx)
[[-118.7558445   171.37619558  -20.37188041  -88.94733652]
 [  -0.56274492    2.49107626   -1.00812489   -0.62648633]
 [-160.35674704  230.3266324   -28.87548299 -116.75862026]
 [ 231.62940572 -334.07044947   42.21936405  170.90926978]]
```

## Edit: workaround

I'm 95% sure that what you've run into is a bug in the Sympy code. It seems that `X0^-1` was valid syntax for Sympy `Matrix` objects at some point, but no longer. However, it seems that someone forgot to tell that to whomever maintains the `lambdify` code, since it still translates every matrix exponentiation into the carrot `^` syntax.

So what you should do is submit an issue on the [Sympy github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues). Just post your code and the error it produces, and ask if that's the intended behavior. In the meantime, here's a filthy hack to work around the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, lambdify

class XormulArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

    def __xor__(self, other):
        return np.linalg.matrix_power(self, other)

X0 = MatrixSymbol('X0',2,2)
xx = np.random.rand(4,4)
X0Inv = X0.inv()
symInv = lambdify(X0,X0Inv,'numpy')

print('result of symInv(XormulArray(xx))')
print(symInv(XormulArray(xx)), end='\n\n')

print('result of np.linalg.inv(xx)')
print(np.linalg.inv(xx))
```

Output:

```
result of symInv(XormulArray(xx))
[[ 3.50382881 -3.84573344  3.29173896 -2.01224981]
 [-1.88719742  1.86688465  0.3277883   0.0319487 ]
 [-3.77627792  4.30823019 -5.53247103  5.53412775]
 [ 3.89620805 -3.30073088  4.27921307 -4.68944191]]

result of np.linalg.inv(xx)
[[ 3.50382881 -3.84573344  3.29173896 -2.01224981]
 [-1.88719742  1.86688465  0.3277883   0.0319487 ]
 [-3.77627792  4.30823019 -5.53247103  5.53412775]
 [ 3.89620805 -3.30073088  4.27921307 -4.68944191]]
```

Basically, you'll have to cast all of your arrays to the thin wrapper type `XormulArray` right before you pass them into `symInv`. This hack is not best practice for a bunch of reasons (including the fact that it apparently breaks the `(2,2)` shape restriction you placed on `X0`), but it'll probably be the best you can do until the Sympy codebase is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Indeed, using `np.power(X0,-1)` fixes the exception, but it is not a true inversion.

Comment: My thought was that since `**` is power operator in python, sympy will apply it to matrices in a correct way as it does with scalars, but  apparently it is not the case.
When I try set `X0Inv = np.linalg.inv(X0)` of course I get another exception as it is a semantically wrong statement.  So now the question is how to explain to sympy that I need true maxtrix inversion so that lambify doesn't fail..

Comment: @Ant I added a filthy hack to my answer that can be used to work around the problem and get a `lambdify` expression to calculate the matrix inverse. I also added a suggestion that you submit a bug report to the [Sympy github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues). That's the only way that your problem will get fixed for real.

Comment: thanks a lot, this approach works for me as well.  With my current python experience it would take a long while to find the solution. Yes, I will open a ticket on the github. Thanks again.